# Read access to user's nodes based for referenced users

Tags: nodes, users

I am trying to figure out how to provide access to nodes of the users, which have referenced users. Please note that users are referenced not from nodes, but the user profiles, so I can not use the [Node access user reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/nodeaccess_userreference) module. I also can not use roles-based access modules, because otherwise there would be too many roles to create as users on this website should be able to reference unlimited users. I also can not user organic groups.

So basically users have other users referenced from their profiles. All referenced users should have access to nodes authored by the users who referenced them.

Comment: How did you implement that " users are referenced ... user profiles"? Is that an entity reference field in which the user adds a reference to each user that should have access? Also, what's the reason why you cannot use Organic Groups?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That will require [custom code](https://www.drupal.org/developing/modules/7).

Here's one way to achieve it:

You'll need to use [hook_node_view](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_view/7.x) to get involved when the node is about to be rendered.  Your code should:

1. Check the node's author and use [user_load](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_load/7.x) to gain access to the referenced users
2. Check to see if the current user (`global $user`) is in the list of referenced users
3. Permit or deny the node view, or change how the node displays, depending on the result.

Comment: Fair enough. I thought so myself, but hoped there is already some kind of ready-to-use solution.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, it's a pretty niche use-case I think.